# Can't exclude web.config file while publishing using dotnet publish command

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, msbuild

I have a dot net core 3.1 project. When I run my application using IIS it creates a ***web.config*** file automatically by adding environment ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" = "Development". Since I am deploying my application to Azure and managing configuration via application settings, I don't need to publish the ***web.config*** file in my artifact folder. Also, the added ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT causes change the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT from Staging/Production to Development as well. I wanted to exclude the ***web.config*** while publishing. I have tried with different approaches suggested online but nothing works like:

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Remove="web.config" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Update="web.config">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Update="web.config">
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
```

But it always includes the ***web.config*** file in published directory for **dotnet publish** command.
Is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/8760), you should add the following section in the .csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks @GoodboY, it solved my issue! It has to be use with <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory> for the web.config file.

Comment: @Samrat: Where does this go, your <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>?